# Retrieve filename Without extension from file full path

Tags: c#, string, replace, filenames

I have a list of files and need to retrieve the filename(s) (Without extension) from file full path.

I generated a list print in command prompt (with path inside intentionally); and I need to replace the path with something else.

i.e:
[This is the *.txt file with generated content example]

```
C:\folder\files\img1.png  
C:\folder\files\img2.png  
C:\folder\files\img3.png  
C:\folder\files\img4.png  
...etc...
```

What im trying to achieve:
Img1.png.  or   Img1

I'm using the code bellow, but I don’t know how to use it correctly yet.

[Original Code]

```
File.WriteAllText("Path", Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText("Path"), "[Pattern]", "Replacement"));
```

[The same code; but modified]

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Folder\Files\print.txt", Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Folder\Files\print.txt"), "[C:\folder\files\]", "Copy "));
```

Comment: Try File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Folder\Files\print.txt", Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Folder\Files\print.txt"), @"C:\folder\files", "Copy "));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can use it. You do not need to use RegEx in this case, because the string which you want to replace is well defined:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Folder\Files\print.txt", File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Folder\Files\print.txt").Replace(@"C:\folder\files\", "Copy "));
```

Comment: =D WOW! That simple!?
It worked Great.
Huge Thanks "outcoldman"

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use [GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) and provide the string-value(s)? You can append the output to a string-builder and just rewrite the file.